# Numbers that are a power of their sum of digits Codewars

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I'm stuck in Codewars Kata, I hope someone could help me out (without spoiling the solution).
In fact the problem is that I didn't fully understand how it should work, I got the idea of the exercise but things are a bit confusing especially in Sample tests.

Here are the instructions:

> The number 81 has a special property, a certain power of the sum of its digits is equal to 81 (nine squared). Eighty one (81), is the first number in having this property (not considering numbers of one digit). The next one, is 512. Let's see both cases with the details.
>
> 8 + 1 = 9 and 9^2 = 81
>      512 = 5 + 1 + 2 = 8 and 8^3 = 512

We need to make a function, power_sumDigTerm(), that receives a number n and may output the nth term of this sequence of numbers. The cases we presented above means that:

```
power_sumDigTerm(1) == 81
power_sumDigTerm(2) == 512
```

And here are the sample tests:

```
test.describe("Example Tests")
test.it("n = " + str(1))
test.assert_equals(power_sumDigTerm(1), 81)
test.it("n = " + str(2))
test.assert_equals(power_sumDigTerm(2), 512)
test.it("n = " + str(3))
test.assert_equals(power_sumDigTerm(3), 2401)
test.it("n = " + str(4))
test.assert_equals(power_sumDigTerm(4), 4913)
test.it("n = " + str(5))
test.assert_equals(power_sumDigTerm(5), 5832)
```

My main problem is how did they get the results for the sample tests.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Why is how they got the results your main problem? Why does it matter and what do you want with respect to that?

Comment: If you want more examples, you can see the sequence [on OEIS](http://oeis.org/A128912)

Comment: @martineau I want to understand how things work in these examples because the code I'm writing should satisfy all cases in the Sample tests and random ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PeterdeRivaz

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow is mainly for coding questions, and what you're asking really isn't one.

Comment: Even if this is the first step to get to codding I'm confused to hear that this has nothing to do with codding.
However I'm deleting this one now.

Comment: @martineau: SO also accepts questions appropriately related to programming; the `algorithms` tag is a prime example.

Answer (score 2):

A good speed up trick is to not check all numbers, Any such number must be of the form a^b for integers a and b. If you find a way to enumerate those and check them you will have a fairly efficient solution.

Comment: That is helpful much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On f(5), the sum of the numbers is 5+8+3+2 = 18. And 18^3=5832.
Brute force method would look like this for the next one:
Start at 5833, add the digits, check the powers of the sum to see if you get number. This would actually be very fast as you can see that last one only got to ^3. As soon as the power is larger than the number you are seeking, move on to the next number: 5834. When you find one, insert into a table to remember it.

The number theory experts may be able to find a more efficient method but this brute force method is likely to be pretty fast.

Comment: For the last test we should get 5 as an answer, 5+8+3+2 = 18
for i in range(1,11):
   print(18**i)
we get :
18
324
5832
104976
1889568
34012224
612220032
11019960576
198359290368
3570467226624
None of these powers nth element is 5 how is 5 an answer then ?

Comment: checking a number is fast, but looking at the first few numbers we fear there may not be so many of these numbers, and the next number might be far away forcing us to check many numbers.

Comment: No we do not have to check many numbers. Take that next one for example: 5833: 5+8+3+3 = 19. 19^2 = 361. 19^3 = 6859. Done already because 6859 > 5833. I would guess even a brute force algorithm would take less than a second to find the next one that is valid.

Comment: A working algorithm would have to check for traps. Example: 10,000. Sum of the numbers is 1. 1 to any power is 1. Make sure your program does not get stuck in an infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

Grab a prime generator; you need only prime powers to generate the sequence (although you will have all integers >= 2 in the test for inclusion).  This is because if a number is a composite power, it's also a prime power.

Maintain a list of current powers, indexed by the base integer.  For instance, once you've made it to a limit of 100, you'll have the list

```
[0, 0, 64, 81, 64, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
// Highest power no greater than the current limit
```

... and the current list of target numbers has only one element: `[81]`

Extending the limit:

- Pick the lowest number in the list (25 = 5^2, in this case)
- Multiply by its base: 25 => 125
- Check: is 1+2+5 a root of 125?  (There are minor ways to speed this up)
- If so, add 125 to the list

Now, go back to all lower integers (the range [2, 5-1] ), and add any smaller prime powers of those integers.  (I haven't worked out whether there can ever be more than one power to add for a given integer; that's an interesting prime-based problem.)

Whenever you add a new target number, make sure you insert in numerical order; the step in the previous paragraph may introduce a "hit" lower than the one that triggered the iteration.  For instance, this *could* append `5832` before in finds `4913` (I haven't coded and executed this algorithm).  You *could* collect all the added target numbers, sort that list, and append them as a block.

Although complicated, I believe that this will be notably faster than the brute-force methods given elsewhere.

Comment: awesome this one seems a good idea I'll give it a try and give you my feedback after that, thanks for your answer by the way.